# Logout success url with spring security 6 and SAML2

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0

I have set up a login/logout to a SAML2 SSO with Spring Security. Everything is working fine, but the problem is that I can't find a way to redirect the application to a specific page after a successful logout instead of the index. I have looked at the documentation and many Stack Overflow threads, and it seems like this is how it's done:

```
.saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2
                        .authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider))
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutOk"))
                .saml2Logout((saml2) -> saml2
                        .logoutRequest((request) -> request.logoutUrl("/SLOService.saml2"))
                        .logoutResponse((response) -> response.logoutUrl("/SLOService.saml2"))
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
```

, but it's not working for me. I've been stuck for days with this seemingly trivial issue.